# How to Insert Many In mongodb and remove duplicated automatic

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I try to add List of bson-Document  using for each  in mongodb from c#, but i need to remove duplicated  if it exist automatic 
I try to make it as a key but it throw exception  duplicated key.

Comment: try `$addToSet`

Comment: every time i insert bulk it is unique but i has the same in db  so i need to update or ignore the existing item  @Saravana

Comment: If you insert documents one by one inside a loop, you can use _update_ with the _upsert_ option. It replaces all fields in an existing document or insert a new one if it does not exist. I don't know how to write the query in c#, but in JavaScript it looks like this: `db.collection.update({ _id: "doc_id" },   {_id: "doc_id", attr1: "value", ...}, { upsert: true })`. This way you will replace duplicates (documents with same _id) with newer versions.

Comment: Element name 'name of property"' is not valid'.  this error  mean any thing for you @AndriySimonov

Comment: @HudaTwfik Unfortunately not. To get help on this issue you'd better ask a new question where you describe what you want to achieve, what code you execute, and what error message you get.